# Spring security -remember me

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to implement remember me in my application using spring security.
I am not getting right approach to do..
can any one help me to how to proceed .. My spring-security config file is as given here:=-

```
<security:http disable-url-rewriting="true"
    use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint"
    access-denied-page="/pages/access_denied.jsp" create-session="never"  >

    <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationFilter"
        position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
    <security:logout invalidate-session="true"
        logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" success-handler-ref="logoutHandler" />
</security:http>
<!-- Bean for handling logout -->
<bean id="logoutHandler" class="se.etm.ewo.web.security.filter.LogoutHandler" />
<!-- Temporary internal authentication manager -->
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider
        ref="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService">
        <ref bean="userDao" />
    </property>
    <property name="passwordEncoder">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PlaintextPasswordEncoder" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/pages/login.jsp" />
    <property name="forceHttps" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean name="authenticationFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager">
        <ref bean="authenticationManager" />
    </property>
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl">
        <value>/j_login</value>
    </property>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler" />

    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
            <constructor-arg>
                <value>/loginFailed.do</value>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="successHandler"
    class="se.etm.ewo.web.security.authentication.RoleBasedAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="roleToUrlMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="SYSADMIN" value="/secure/loginSubmit.do" />
            <entry key="ADMIN" value="/secure/loginSubmit.do" />
            <entry key="ORGADMIN" value="/secure/loginSubmit.do" />
            <entry key="USER" value="/secure/loginSubmit.do" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="loggerListener"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.event.LoggerListener" />
```

Comment: try adding what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

You seem to go to great lengths to configure everything without the namespace, most of what you have done can be done with the namespace.

```
<security:http  disable-url-rewriting="true"
                use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" 
                access-denied-page="/pages/access_denied.jsp" create-session="never"  >

    <security:login-form authentication-success-handler-ref="successHandler" login-processing-url="/j_login" login-page="/pages/login.jsp" authentication-failure-url="/loginFailed.do"/>
    <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" success-handler-ref="logoutHandler" />

</security:http>
<!-- Bean for handling logout -->
<bean id="logoutHandler" class="se.etm.ewo.web.security.filter.LogoutHandler" />

<!-- Temporary internal authentication manager -->

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userdao"/>
    <property name="passwordEncoder">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PlaintextPasswordEncoder" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="successHandler" class="se.etm.ewo.web.security.authentication.RoleBasedAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="roleToUrlMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="SYSADMIN" value="/secure/loginSubmit.do" />
            <entry key="ADMIN" value="/secure/loginSubmit.do" />
            <entry key="ORGADMIN" value="/secure/loginSubmit.do" />
            <entry key="USER" value="/secure/loginSubmit.do" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="loggerListener" class="org.springframework.security.access.event.LoggerListener" />
```

This should yield the same results. Now you should be able to add the `<security:remember-me />` tag with the proper configuration. A simple `<security:remember-me key="myAppKey"/>` should be enough to enable it. See the [Spring Security Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#remember-me) chapter about Remember me. For more configuration options see [the namespace description](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-remember-me).

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am using proper namespace. it is not an issue, every things works fine. your suggestion, I have already tried but this is for auto config = "true". Here I am taking auto config ="false".  which needs to write custom filters

Comment: No you don't, "auto-config=true" only registers some defaults (which is also not recommended to be used anymore), you can always use the namespace to configure additional things. Half of your original configuration is defaults which you can simply configure with the namespace (which is what I did in the modified config). You don't need all the additional declarations even if you don't use auto-config. That is your big misconception/misunderstanding.